# Asp.net website design consideration & redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture, webforms, multilingual

I have designed multilingual website in English & Arabic while keeping one page for both languages and use different CSS files for English & Arabic along with resource files. This approach is good but difficult to handle if we have different feature for same pages which limit the design.

I am designing new website and thought of having separate .ASPX page for English & Arabic version. In New design i will keep English version files under "en" folder and Arabic under "ar" folder and i will use Default.aspx file to detect browser language & redirect user to particular language version.

This way i can have multilingual website with more flexibility but will make managing website slightly time consuming.

Now my Question is what approach should i use to redirect to particular version, should i use general response.redirect approach or i should do a proper 301 redirect.

I am not sure what would be best & Search Engine friendly approach.

Website Development in ASP.Net 4.0 Web Forms, C# 3.0

I would appreciate if someone can recommend a better approach or how i can design it in more professional way.

Answer (score 0):

Search engines do in fact differentiate between 301 and 302 redirects. By using 302 that means that the page has been moved temporary to a new location which might confuse search engines.

You can perform a permanent redirect in ASP.NET 4.0 using Response.RedirectPermanent.

This link explains in more detail the difference between 302 and 301 redirects:
http://www.hochmanconsultants.com/articles/301-versus-302.shtml

Comment: I am aware of the fact but i am not sure if i redirect from root folder to sub language folder is a correct approach. will it effect me on search engines

Answer (score 0):

To answer the redirect question, you should use a proper 301 redirect if you decide to set your solution up that way.

To answer the more general question of what the correct architecture is, I would refrain from using language detection combined with an automatic redirect. There are a couple of reasons:

- Search engine bots may not send across any user string. For that reason, at best they are only going to pick up one version of the site, and at worst there will be a problem and they won't pick up any.
- There is a high likelihood of getting the detection wrong. For example what if someone has their language set to French? Where do you send them?

Instead, what you should do is have a language toggle in the navigation (or wherever you think is appropriate) that takes you to the corresponding page in the other language. This will both allow users to easily switch to the appropriate language as well as ensure that bots can properly index both versions of your website (as an added bonus, it also ensures that the bot sees the other version of that page, the search engine will then take care of identifying the language).

Comment: Sellandb: I am doing auto detection of two languages only like Arabic & English and redirect them to folder ar/en. English is the default language if neither of the two language is set for example if a user has french then user will be redirected to English version. My site structure is like `Root folder and two sub-folder English & Arabic. root folder will have default.aspx file which will detect browser language and redirect to Arabic or English .